# Attaching a Completed DocuSign Document to a Salesforce Standard Object (Not Opportunities)

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I'm trying to attach a completed DocuSign document to the Contact or Account record that initiated the document (within Notes or Notes & Attachments).

I've found instructions for [attaching documents to an Opportunity](https://support.docusign.com/articles/DocuSign-for-Salesforce-Adding-Completed-Documents-to-the-Notes-and-Attachments-New) as well as attaching to [custom objects](https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-admin-guide-add-ds-status-to-custom-object). I've walked through these steps and tried to tailor the instructions for a Contact and Account record but with no success.

Please let me know the steps I can take to accomplish this. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are communicating with docusign via a REST API then you should be receiving a base64 response. You would pass the response body into the 'execute' method below and it should insert to the specified contact and related account. The logic leading up to this would need to query the specific contact and account, but the code here is an example of pulling an existing salesforce ContentVersion and create a new content document from it. Also, you would need to either parse the incoming base64 data to determine the file information *(extension, title)* or match the extension within the response body. Your go to links would be as follows:

[Salesforce Reference- ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)

[Salesforce Reference- EncodingUtil](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm)

[Salesforce Reference- ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm)

[DocuSign API Docs- Envelopes](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get#responses)

Hope this helps!

```
public with sharing class uploadDocument {
//Build this to accept whatever you need to relate the document to
public Contact ourContact {get; set;}
//Init
public uploadDocument() {
    ourContact = [SELECT Id, Name, AccountId FROM Contact LIMIT 1];
}

public static void execute(String base64EncodedDocument){
    uploadDocument classObject = new uploadDocument();
    String extension;
    //Conditional logic will need to be added if you want to handle other file types
    if(base64EncodedDocument.contains('pdf')){
        extension = 'pdf';
    }
    //Prep the raw document for insert via the ContentVersion class
    Blob base64DecodedDocument = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64EncodedDocument);
    ContentVersion sfDocumentObject = new ContentVersion();
    sfDocumentObject.VersionData = base64DecodedDocument;
    sfDocumentObject.Title =  'Our Test Document';
    sfDocumentObject.FirstPublishLocationId = classObject.ourContact.Id;
    sfDocumentObject.PathOnClient = '//' + sfDocumentObject.Title + '.' + extension;
    insert sfDocumentObject;
    //Add additional references for the document
    List<additionalIdLink> additionalLinks = new List<additionalIdLink>();
    additionalIdLink accountLink = new additionalIdLink();
    accountLink.linkedId = classObject.ourContact.AccountId;
    accountLink.documentId = sfDocumentObject.Id;
    additionalLinks.add(accountLink);
    linkToAdditionalRecords(JSON.serialize(additionalLinks));
}
//Ignore, just for testing purposes
//I uploaded a document just to test it and everything worked just fine, preview includedS
private static String setupExample(){
    ContentVersion ourTestDocument = [SELECT Id, FileExtension, FileType, Title, VersionData, VersionNumber FROM ContentVersion WHERE Title =: 'Getting Started With Salesforce' ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC][0];
    String result = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(ourTestDocument.VersionData);
    return result;
}
//Ignore, just for testing purposes
public static void executeExample(){
    String base64DocumentReceived = setupExample();
    execute(base64DocumentReceived);
}
//Quick Access class to pass the previous values to the Future method
public class additionalIdLink{
    public String linkedId {get; set;}
    public String documentId {get; set;}
}
//Allows you to link to as many additional records as you need. I haven't run into any use cases where you will be adding over 200 links at a time, but it will throw a query exception if you attempt that
@future
public static void linkToAdditionalRecords(String jsonLinks){
    List<additionalIdLink> links = (List<additionalIdLink>)JSON.deserialize(jsonLinks, List<additionalIdLink>.class);
    List<ContentDocumentLink> result = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
    for(additionalIdLink link : links){
        ContentDocumentLink accountLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
        String documentId = [SELECT Id, VersionNumber, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =: link.documentId LIMIT 1].ContentDocumentId;
        accountLink.ContentDocumentId = documentId;
        accountLink.LinkedEntityId = link.linkedId;
        accountLink.ShareType = 'V';
        accountLink.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
        result.add(accountLink);
    }
    if(result.size() > 0){
        insert result;
    }
}
```

}